# Add div onClick function and toggle the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just built up this page where I am trying to create an event where clicking on **Task Matrix** (from Section-1) - Section-2 will appear and click on Section-2, Section-3 will appear.

I have written this sample html with the help of this [Toggle_division_add_Link](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7gyrB/4/)

```js
<!-- So far I have tried this Jquery-->

<script>
    function addCode(){
        var newCode= '<div class="2">2</div>'
        alert(1);
        $('.1').click(function(){
            var $this = $(this), $2=$this.next('.2');
            alert(2);
            if ($2.length) {
               $2.toggle();
            } 
            else {
                $(newCode).insertAfter($this);
            }
        )};
    };
    addCode();
</script>
```

```css
.header2{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);;
    padding:5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Section 1-->
<div class="header2">
    <div class="taskMatrix"><span>Task Matrix</span></div>
    <div class="handOver"><span> Handover</span></div>
    <div class="teamDetails"><span>Team Details</span></div>
</div>

<!-- Section 2-->
<div class="header3">
    <div class="addTask" style="display:inline-block"><span>Task Matrix Report</span></div>
    <div class="addTask" style="display:inline-block"><span>Add Task</span></div>
</div>

<!-- Section 3-->
<div class="body1" style="color:green">
    <nav>
        Current Task<br>
        Handover<br>
        PrioritiseTask<br>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Task Matrix</th>
                    <th>Tirthankar</th>  
                    <th>Sandip</th>
                    <th>Arnab</th>
                    <th>Rajdeep</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Upload Daily Dashboard</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>n</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Upload Daily Dashboard</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>n</td>
                <td>n</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Send 1pm CST report</td>
                <td>n</td>
                <td>n</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Send 3pm CST excel</td>     
                <td>y</td>
                <td>n</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>n</td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Send 5pm CST report</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>  
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Task update on the portal</td>     
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>
                <td>y</td>  
           </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just wrap the sections in a `div` and give that id's like `section1`, `section2` and `section3`? Then you can use that as a selector.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/94fbouah/6/ : now onclicking TaskMatrixReport div should be appeared.... any update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think this is what you are after...

```
function addCode() { 
    var section3 = $('#section3');

    $('#taskMatrix').click(function(){
        $('#section2').toggle();

        if(section3.is(":visible")) {
            section3.toggle();
        }
    });

    $('#taskMatrixReport').click(function() {
        section3.toggle();
    });    
};

addCode();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94fbouah/11/

1) you were using a class that doesn't exist to bind the click event, so none of it would work
2) the example you were working from doesn't do what you want it to, so you don't need most of it
3) also set some display:none inline css, can be removed if hidden on load not required

Comment: hi Michael- if I want to call only one class like "addTask" instead of "header3" --> I mean on clicking "Task Matrix Report" ; then what would be the probabable change here ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/94fbouah/6/ : now onclicking TaskMatrixReport div should be appeared.... any update ?

Comment: hi micheal - above fiddle jsfiddle.net/94fbouah/8 is working fine - but just one thing is: clicking on TaskMatrix->section2->section3,if I click on TaskMatrix now,section2 is toggling, not section2 & section3 as a whole. Any suggestion here >

Answer (score 1):

Update below script

```
$(function(){
var newCode= '<div class="2">2</div>'
alert(1);
 $('.1').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this),
   $2=$this.next('.2');
   alert(2);
   if ($2.length) {
      $2.toggle();
    } 
    else {
       $(newCode).insertAfter($this);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/94fbouah/6/ : now onclicking TaskMatrixReport div should be appeared.... any update ?